# Plotting heatmap in R given z coordinate

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

Very new to R and I'm trying to plot a "smooth" heatmap for clicks per screen pixel. The data is given in the following format:

```
x1, y1, count1
x2, y2, count2
x3, y3, count3
...
```

Where `countN` is the number of times user clicked on a pixel `xN, yN`.
The most smooth thing I've found so far is kernel density estimation using `kde2d`, but when I'm using it like `kde2d(data[,1], data[,2])` it throws away the `count` number.

How do I take that number into account? If all methods require only 2 coordinates to build a heatmap, how do I unroll my 3-column array to 2-column array so that

```
1, 1, 2
2, 3, 1
```

becomes

```
1, 1
1, 1
2, 3
```

Comment: You can turn that data into a matrix to build a `raster` object and there are many options for utilizing the counts (contour plot, etc). [This](http://www.spatialcapability.com/Library/Rspatialcourse_CMIS_PDF%20Standard.pdf) would be a good starter reference.

Comment: Some sample data would help ppl help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the Kernel density using `kde2d` you want to use,

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2),y = c(3,1),count=c(2,1))
f1=kde2d(x=rep.int(df$x,df$count),
         y=rep.int(df$x,df$count)) # you probably also want to set the parameters h,n, and lims
image(f1)
```

see `?kde2d` for other parameters.